# Unir DataFrames en pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo dos DataFrames, el primero **df_subset** tiene una tres variables donde **RD_GDP** es la inversión en I+D por país en porcentaje del PBI

df_subset

```
     country  year    RD_GDP
0        AUS  1981  0.902542
1        AUS  1984  1.023905
2        AUS  1986  1.179149
3        AUS  1987  1.137756
4        AUS  1988  1.163591
     ...   ...       ...
1305     LTU  2014  1.031138
1306     LTU  2015  1.044081
1307     LTU  2016  0.842334
1308     LTU  2017  0.896408
1309     LTU  2018  0.876656
```

El segundo DataFrame **df_subset_gdp** tiene también tres variables donde **GDP_PC** es el PBI per cápita por país y año.

```
    country  year         GDP_PC
0       AUS  2015   47304.816745
1       AUS  2016   50284.172793
2       AUS  2017   51297.139196
3       AUS  2018   53700.680893
4       AUS  2019   54752.242834
..      ...   ...            ...
265     MAR  2017    7582.794999
266     SGP  2015   86972.563073
267     SGP  2016   89396.724443
268     SGP  2017   94945.250892
269     SGP  2018  101280.413499
```

Necesito unir los dos DataFrames para poder hacer un **Scatterplot** de las dos variables que mencioné y ver la relación, entonces para unirlos intenté el siguiente comando

```
dataset_merge = df_subset.merge(df_subset_gdp, left_on = "year", right_on = "year")
```

El problema es que obtengo lo siguiente sin tener ordenado **GDP_PC** por **country_x**

```
  country_x  year    RD_GDP country_y        GDP_PC
0       AUS  2015  1.875612       AUS  47304.816745
1       AUS  2015  1.875612       AUT  49955.456118
2       AUS  2015  1.875612       BEL  46214.082208
3       AUS  2015  1.875612       CAN  44671.409504
4       AUS  2015  1.875612       CZE  33701.384000
```

Comment: Hola, parece que hay datos para ciertos años que existen en un dataframe y no en otro, ¿descartas estos años (los que no tiene datos para ambos indices) para ese país?¿Dejas que GDP_PC sea NaN para ese año si no existe el dato pero si existe RD_GDP y viceversa?

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla cuando mergeo los dataframe me elimina esos datos para los que no hay datos para una variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma de solucionar tu problema es creando una lista para **left_on** y **right_on** de esta manera vas a poder unir los dataframe de acuerdo al país y al año.

```
dataset_merge = df_subset.merge(df_subset_gdp, how="inner", 
                                left_on = ["country","year"], right_on = ["country","year"])
```

El resultado es el siguiente

```
 country  year    RD_GDP        GDP_PC
0     AUS  2015  1.875612  47304.816745
1     AUS  2017  1.789384  51297.139196
2     AUT  2015  3.049690  49955.456118
3     AUT  2016  3.116588  52614.377745
4     AUT  2017  3.048855  54652.468293
```